# Prepopulating field(s) with Javascript returns NULL on Spring MVC form submit

Tags: javascript, spring, forms, spring-mvc

The title is a clear description of my issue.

The pre-populated values are pre-entered in the field and are displayed as expected but just do not go through to the controller I guess?

Here's some code on the fields that are pre-populated but do not work, I am not sure where to start!

Here's two vars that do not pre-populate.

```
    var fullDate = new Date()
    var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) :(fullDate.getMonth()+1);
    var currentDate = fullDate.getDate() + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
    $("#declarationSignature").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#declartionDate").prop("disabled",true);
    $("#declarationSignature").val($("#title").val() + " " + $("#firstName").val()+ " " + $("#lastName").val());
    $("#declartionDate").val(currentDate);
```

Some recalled a data that is not saved with spring (Third var)

```
var selectedLocations = JSON.parse(storedValue);
console.log("parsing selected locations")
console.log(selectedLocations )
$('#storesAppliedFor').val(selectedLocations );
```

Comment: avoid the use of disabled it will not submit the value to controller. use readonly instead.

Comment: @Alien thank you, I was looking for an alternative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the disabled property, value was not posted.

Removing disabled tag on submit resolved the issue.